# json_encode() Not Escaping Double Commas in Certain Situations

Tags: php, json

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/hd0t-ebjr

```
<?php
    require "simple_html_dom.php";

    $html = file_get_html("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlambeer.RidiculousFishing&hl=en");

    $test = $html->find('.id-app-orig-desc', 0)->innertext;

    $data = [
        'test' => $test
    ];

    die(var_dump(json_encode($data)));
?>
```

Scroll down and you'll notice that all the double quotes are not escaped correctly.  Although other characters are ("/" for example).

The weird thing is, that I can't seem to reproduce it when copying the test string into the php code.  Only when loading it from the url.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot. Thanks to @Moriarty for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These double quotes are not really double quotes. They are just entity html, `&quot;`, no need to escape it.

Comment: Damn, so simple... I forgot the `html_entity_decode()`.  I'll mark this as correct as soon as I'm allowed to. Thanks!